# Validation of the text field for search problems

Tags: javascript, search

I have a search box that has a default value as "Search",i need to write some javascript that checks if the  value in the search box is either "Search" or empty, then i should not sent the request and  i need to display "Please enter a keyword"`

Here is the code

```
    <div id="search">
    <form action="/" style="" method="post" name="searchForm" id="searchForm" onSubmit="grabSearch();">
    <img src="/images/bg_search_left.jpg" id="search_box_left" width="5" height="32" alt="" />
    <input id="search_box" type="text" value="Search"  onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}"/>
    <input type="image" id="search_arrow" src="/images/bg_search_right.jpg" width="34" height="32" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_page" value="SEARCH" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="SEARCH" />
    <input type="hidden" name="searchTerm" value="" />
    </form>
    </div>



    function grabSearch(){

    var search=document.getElementById('search_box').value;
    if(search="Search"||search=""){
        document.getElementById('search_box').value="Please Enter a keyword"
    }
    search=encodeSearch(search);
    document.forms['searchForm'].searchTerm.value = search;
 }
```

On form submit i am checking it and displaying the message "Please Enter a keyword". Although the message is displayed in the text field but the request is sent(which i don't want to happen) and also on focus of the text field i want the message(please enter a keyword)to go way too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Jeaffrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172637/validation-of-the-text-field-for-search-problems/8172684#8172684), you are not using the correct comparison operators.  It should be:

```
if(search === "Search" || search === ""){
    document.getElementById('search_box').value="Please Enter a keyword";
    return false;
}
```

After that change, you need to return that value from your onSubmit -

```
<form action="www.google.com" style="" method="post" name="searchForm" id="searchForm" onsubmit="return grabSearch();">
```

Comment: Form is being submitted but the please enter a keyword message is displayed though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to return false?

```
if(search == "Search" || search == ""){
    document.getElementById('search_box').value="Please Enter a keyword";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No. it is still submitting the form and i am getting back the response which i don't want